# Sending HTTP Get and Post request from android without httpClient

Tags: android, httprequest, android-networking

I trying to consume a webservice rest from and Android app, but when I look for examples and found only two ways, with httpClient which is deprecated and I can't even import for my application for it version, and, a method with HttpURLConnection which, doesn't work like expected.

My code right in this moment:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class RestConnect  {
    public static String listar() throws IOException {
       try {
           URL reqURL = new URL("http://localhost/wsRest/index.php/contact");
           HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) (reqURL.openConnection());
           request.setRequestMethod("GET");
           request.connect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Nope!";
        }
        return "YESSSS!";
    }
}
```

How can I access my URL and easily get it content, which Get and Post methods?

Much thanks everyone!

Comment: define `doesn't work as expected`.

Comment: Like nothing happens and throws an exception... even if follow the example like I did in the code above

Comment: then, at least, look at the exception...

Answer (score 1):

Better use awesome http library https://github.com/square/okhttp

For example, try this snippet:

```
  private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

  public void run() throws Exception {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("http://publicobject.com/helloworld.txt")
        .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

    Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
    for (int i = 0; i < responseHeaders.size(); i++) {
      System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
    }

    System.out.println(response.body().string());
  }
```

Another great solution (also from [square](http://square.github.io/) team), is [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit)

Comment: I follow the example but it doesn't work
this command "Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();" throws an exception but the message is null

Comment: What kind of exception you get?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 URL url = new URL(urlpath.toString()); // Your given URL.
     HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
     c.setRequestMethod("GET");
c.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
        c.setUseCaches(false);
        c.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        c.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
        c.setReadTimeout(timeout);
        c.connect();
        int status = c.getResponseCode();

        switch (status) {
            case 200:
            case 201:
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line+"\n");
                }
                br.close();
                return sb.toString();
        }
```